# Using IFS rather than whitepace in bash

Tags: bash, echo, ifs

There is a quite nasty expression that  want to echo using bash.

The expression is:

```
'one two --
```

**Note:** There is white space after `--`.

So I have:

```
IFS=
echo 'one$IFStwoIFS--$IFS
```

But the result is:

```
one$IFStwo$IFS--$IFS
```

Comment: You have a typo - it is `IFS`, not `ISF`.   Also, you don't have the completing single quote.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/6862601).

Comment: @codeforester just a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few issues with your approach:

1. Within single quote variables are not expanded in shell
2. In the string `one$IFStwo$IFS--$IFS` first instance of `$IFS` will not be expanded since you have string `two` next to `$IFS` so it attempts to expand **non-existent variable** `$IFStwo`.
3. Default value of `$IFS` is `$' \t\n'`

You can use:

```
echo "one${IFS}two$IFS--$IFS"
```

which will expand to (`cat -A` output):

```
one ^I$
two ^I$
-- ^I$
```

Comment: Try this: `( IFS=' ' && echo "<one${IFS}two$IFS--$IFS>"; )`

Comment: good... this worked: `IFS=' ';echo$IFS"'or${IFS}true$IFS--$IFS"`. pardon. If i replace something else with `IFS=' ' `. I mean I want to replace something else with whitespace in `IFS=' '`. What should I do/

Comment: Didn't get but `( IFS=':'; echo "<one${IFS}two$IFS--$IFS>"; )` also works fine.

Comment: I need a character else instead of whitespace but working as whitespace... when I run bash I need to hide whitespace

Comment: Really thank you for supporting me. I mean what special character I can use in `IFS=' '` instead of whitespace?

Comment: I have `IFS=':'` which is not same as `IFS=''` . May be you mean something else but it is not clear from comments. I suggest you edit your question and clarify

Comment: I mean some methods like this: `IFS=$'\x20';echo$IFS"'first${IFS}second$IFS--$IFS"`. any other idea? :)

Comment: `( IFS=$'\x20' && echo$IFS"<first${IFS}second$IFS--$IFS>"; )` works fine for me